# Partial monoid in the category of categories of modules: The spotty nature of monad composition

Tags: ct.category-theory, modules, monads

It seems that I am working on a conjecture in category theory.  In particular, I am curious about the spotty nature of the composition of monads on Set.  I am guessing that there is a category, $\mathcal{C_M}$, of categories of modules which are all Eilenberg Moore Categories for all the monads on set.  All the monads in set live in a category $\mathcal{Mon}_{\mathit{Set}}$.  I am positing that the category $\mathcal{C_M}$ has a partial monoidal structure.  Furthermore, there should be a monoidal functor from $\mathcal{C_M}$ to $\mathcal{Mon}_{\mathit{Set}}$.  The partial monoidal product should give exact information about the monads that can compose and thus have a distributive law.  If this is all the case, then would it be easy to define the partial monoidal structure on $\mathcal{C_M}$ and then know all the compositions in $\mathcal{Mon}_{\mathit{Set}}$?

Comment: It's hard to make sense of your question, but you will probably run into issues because a pair of monads can have several distributive laws.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks for your input, could it be that there are several partial monoidal products?

Comment: I have rolled back an overly pedantic edit by a user who seems to specialize in this: MO is not a book where consistent conventions of capitalization are required, and in any case, there seems to be precedent for having a "subheading" or "sub-title" where initial letters of words are left un-capitalized